# Column appended to dataframe coming up empty

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

myList = []

path = "/home/reallymemorable/Documents/git/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/*.csv"


for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']

    dateFromFilename = os.path.basename(fname).replace('.csv','')

    fileDate = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [dateFromFilename]})

    myList.append(row.join(fileDate))


concatList = pd.concat(myList, sort=True)

print(concatList)

concatList.to_csv('/home/reallymemorable/Documents/test.csv', index=False, header=True
```

It goes through a folder of CSVs and grabs a specific row and puts it all in a CSV.  The files themselves have names like 10-10-2020.csv.  I have some code in there that gets the filename and removes the file extension, so I am left with the date alone.

I am trying to add another column called "Date" that contains the filename for each file.

The script almost works: it gives me a CSV of all the rows I pulled out of the various CSVs, but the Date column itself is empty.

If I do `print(dateFromFilename)`, the date/filename prints as expected (e.g. `10-10-2020`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `join` has `how=left` by default. And your `fileDate` dataframe has different index than `row`, so you wouldn't get the date. Instead, do an assignment:

```
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']

    dateFromFilename = os.path.basename(fname).replace('.csv','')

    myList.append(row.assign(Date=dateFromFilename))

concatList = pd.concat(myList, sort=True)
```

Another way is to store the dataframes as a dictionary, then concat:

```
myList = dict()

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    row = df.loc[df['Province_State'] == 'Pennsylvania']

    dateFromFilename = os.path.basename(fname).replace('.csv','')

    myList[dateFromFilename] = row

concatList = pd.concat(myList, sort=True)
```